# Why didn't Peter Pettigrew turn into a rat in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

Peter Pettigrew was an Animagus and he could turn into a rat without a wand. In *Deathly Hallows*, when his

> hand started to torture him,

why didn't he turn into a rat and rescue himself?

Comment: Since Peter isn't a capable wizard, I dont think he can do so while in greatly pain. Animagus need at least think they should transform before doing so. In Peter case, a cowardly like him may think he is gonna die and forget to turn. Or Vol spell can nullify it, we havent see Peter turn into rat after voldemort ressurect after all.

Comment: He probably forgot, from shock

Comment: Peter doesn't seem to be a guy who reacts nicely to panic or dangerous situations. I agree with @marcellothearcane.

Comment: the silver hand might be enchanted to prevent him from transforming. Peter had fulfilled his purpose once he revived Voldemort in Book-4; the only reason he was kept along was as a spare.

Comment: As far as I remember, the only described transformation of him into the rat involved usage of Lupin's wand.

Answer (score 3):

When Peter had cut his finger off we could see that he was missing a toenail in rat form also, therefore as he had his whole arm cut off and a new arm given by Voldemort, it would probably show in rat form also and perhaps continue to choke him.

Also if Voldemort could place a spell which can detect betrayal I am sure it would also prevent him from changing into an Animagus seeing as he knew about it.

Comment: This is plain out speculation, which doesn't make a good answer.

Comment: @Roberto speculation is all we have so far, so unless something canon comes up this is the currently best answer.